# How to set Unity as default again?

Tags: unity, gnome

About an hour ago, I asked how I could set Gnome-shell as default desktop interface for Ubuntu replacing Unity, and I was advised to issue this command:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s gnome-shell
```

While this is related to that, it's a different question. Now, how do I set Unity back as default via command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s ubuntu
```

sets Unity 3d as default.